# How can i use sed to remove key properties in plist?

Tags: ios, macos, bash, unix, sed

Example plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.cd.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.cd.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
    <key>file:http://xyx.domain.com/:./</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>./</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://xyx.domain.com/</string>
    </dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
<date>2015-04-18T13:51:58Z</date>
<string>2:8677bc80:5d017c133727de1493558fa4661586b70dfd0f65d8118b381dd76ab60bbe4548c0bfd008dc4314812a32b75d64c971b6</string>
    <key>Values</key>
<dict/>
<key>Version</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

the requirement from the project is "sed" only.
these are the properties in plist file. How can i use sed to find key value start with

```
file:http://xyx.domain.com
```

and delete it from there to

```
</dict>
```

The end result would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.cd.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.cd.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
<date>2015-04-18T13:51:58Z</date>
<string>2:8677bc80:5d017c133727de1493558fa4661586b70dfd0f65d8118b381dd76ab60bbe4548c0bfd008dc4314812a32b75d64c971b6</string>
    <key>Values</key>
<dict/>
<key>Version</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: `sed "file:http:\/\/xyx.domain.com/,/<\/dict>/d"` did not work either

Comment: You seem to have missed the leading `/` in your expression there - `sed '/file:http:.../,/<\/dict>/d'`. And you should use single quotes so the backslashes get passed on to sed instead of eaten by bash's string evaluation/

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$ sed -e '/file:http:\/\/xyx.domain.com/,/<\/dict>/d' filename
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.cd.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.cd.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
    <key>file:http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/:stable</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Distribution</key>
        <string>stable</string>
        <key>Sections</key>
        <array>
            <string>main</string>
        </array>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>deb</string>
        <key>URI</key>
        <string>http://ab.domainCC.com/path/path/</string>
    </dict>
<date>2015-04-18T13:51:58Z</date>
<string>2:8677bc80:5d017c133727de1493558fa4661586b70dfd0f65d8118b381dd76ab60bbe4548c0bfd008dc4314812a32b75d64c971b6</string>
    <key>Values</key>
<dict/>
<key>Version</key>
<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: `-e` doesn't make a difference, it's not necessary unless you have multiple expressions.

Comment: seem like im missing the / . Thanks